# CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)

Tags: css, string, css-selectors

This question has been bugging me for a while now. When writing a CSS selector that compares against an element's attribute like so.

```
a[rel="nofollow"]
```

I never know what I should be doing with the quotation marks. Are they really necessary?

Basically, what is the specification for this because I can't find it on the web site.

Are all of these considered valid?

```
a[rel="nofollow"]
a[rel='nofollow']
a[rel=nofollow]
```

Comment: I don't think they're necessary.

Comment: @Headshota: Not in this exact case, no.

Comment: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes#nofollow

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I’ve written more extensively on the subject here: [**Unquoted attribute values in HTML and CSS**](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values).

I’ve also created a tool to help you answer your question: http://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes

[image: Unquoted attribute value validator]

You can usually omit the quotes as long as the attribute value is alphanumeric (however, there are some exceptions — see the linked article for all the details). Anyhow, I find it to be good practice to add the quotes anyway in case you need them, i.e. `a[href^=http://]` won’t work, but `a[href^="http://"]` will.

The article I mentioned links to the appropriate chapters in the CSS spec.

Comment: @Wolfy87 Updated my answer with a link to an article I wrote the other day. It contains some regexes :)

Comment: (Reproducing my answer as a comment, since I deleted it a while back) From a practical viewpoint: I'd recommend you use quotes, whether single or double. This way any special selector characters within the attribute values (other than the quotes themselves) won't need escaping. Plus — and this is just a personal coding style preference so don't take my word for it — I find it consistent with XHTML attribute quotes.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Amen to that. Do yourself a favor and just use quotes consistently, it saves you a lot of headaches!

Comment: This is an impressive answer, but it doesn't say anything about single quotes (unless I've missed it). Another answer here covers that, though.

Answer (score 30):

> Attribute values must be identifiers or strings

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

The first two use strings. The third uses an identifier.

> identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

> Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single quotes.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings

Comment: Might as well link to CSS3 spec instead: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Comment: CSS2 is actually more helpful because I am in the middle of writing a CSS2 selector engine. So CSS2 is better for me but thanks for the link anyway.