# $("#content a:not(target=_blank)") isn't working.. what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Just a quick one. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$("#content a:not(target=_blank)").live("click", function(){
   alert("You clicked an internal link!!")
})
```

Cheers :)

Comment: What is the intention? What have you tried? What is your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the attribute not equals selector:

```
$("#content a[target!='_blank']").live("click", function(){
   alert("You clicked an internal link!!");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

the jQuery `:not()` selector accepts selectors inside of it, so try something like this:

```
$('#content a:not([target="_blank"])').live("click", function(){
   alert("You clicked an internal link!!")
})
```

Comment: +1 for the technically correct answer in terms of CSS selectors, which makes this potentially a few microseconds faster than jQuery's attribute-not-equals selector.

Comment: I generally don't care about micro-optimization, let's just say I sleep soundly at night even if my script will take 10ms longer then it could have :)

Comment: Neither do I, actually; I purposely used the word "microseconds" to troll anyone who does.

Comment: Ah damn! thanks! Sometimes I find the jQuery documentation a little lacking!

Answer (score 1):

brackets?

```
$("#content a:not([target=_blank])").live("click", function(){
   alert("You clicked an internal link!!") 
})
```

Comment: @BoltClock: That is a relatively new requirement for jQuery or Sizzle or whatever's handling the selectors, is it not?

Comment: @Litek: Ah yeah, I was just talking about CSS selectors in another answer. If it gets processed as a CSS selector then the quotes aren't needed.

Comment: Hmm yeah it does work, I specifically remember a build of jQuery breaking on unquoted values, perhaps it was 1.6.0 or 1.6.1, looks like that was changed for the most recent version? Or am I going crazy and that never happened?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the square brackets for the attribute selector, and quotes around the value.

```
$('#content a:not([target="_blank"])')
```

Single quotes would work here as well.

```
$("#content a:not([target='_blank'])")
```

I believe it was version 1.6.0 where attribute quotes became mandatory, in previous versions it was optional, and this broke a lot of my code wen I updated. It seems 1.6.2 or 1.6.1 may have removed this requirement, although the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) say they are still mandatory. Better to do what they say in case backwards support gets removed in a future version.

As a CSS selector however, it is still optional [for the most part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none/5578880#5578880), so at least get used to using them in jQuery from now on if you haven't already.

Comment: I used to use them in attribute selectors purely because they were required in XHTML/XML attributes. Also, quotes are pretty :P

Comment: I kind of like how the "naked" values look in stylesheets, I don't use quotes around `url()` sources either, it's not necessary so why bother? Optional is optional.

Comment: There are some edge cases where they're required in attributes, though. Albeit, edge cases. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none

Comment: I'd say that using a url or non-alphanum as a value in an attribute selector is not an edge case, I think it's quite relevant. Never knew that and I suspect it's not common knowledge - thanks for showing me that link, probably saved me some head-scratching at some point in the future. I probably would have tried escaping before I thought of quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#content a:not([target='_blank'])").live("click",your_function);
```