# Firefox 12 ignoring styles for input[type="email"]

Tags: css, forms, drupal, styles, drupal-theming

I have a form in the sidebar of a drupal site I'm currently working on. I have specified styles for the `input[type="email"]` element. However firefox does not respect the styles I've dictated. I've tried using the `input[type="email"` selector as well as calling the element by it's id `input#edit-mail` to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This issue is happening in FF v12.

EDIT: Turns out a -ms-filter caused a parse error which caused Firefox to ignore the styles that were dictated after the filter. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: can you show your html code also

Comment: Try without the quotes `input[type=email]`. I could be wrong but I think it's supposed to be without the quotes.

Comment: It should work IMHO. Could you please provide all your relevant code. Or even better a demo on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 12: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWrP3/

Comment: @MrMisterMan: It seems to work for me both with and without the quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The issue turned out to be a parse error caused by a -ms-filter which stopped FF from loading the styles after the filter.

Comment: Turn your comment into an answer and accept it...

Comment: @MrMisterMan: It shouldn't matter. See [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a -ms-filter caused a parse error which caused Firefox to ignore the styles that were dictated after the filter. Thanks for the suggestions.