# How can I use ruby expression interpolation "#{var}" inside nokogiri css selector?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I have been using nokogiri css for a while and i would like to be able to use ruby expression interpolation inside css selectors but it doesn't work. This is the code i would like to use:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.somepage.com'))
keys=["BHiuG", "hUYtb4F", "jefHUY78i"]
keys.each do |k|
    keyvalue = doc.css('span[class="#{k}"]').children
    puts keyvalue
end
```

Is there any way to get a similar syntax working?

Comment: You need double quotes to make them work. `"span[class=\"#{k}\"]"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Nokogiri: the problem is that you are using single quotes but string interpolation in Ruby requires double quotes. Since [single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578903/188031) are also allowed on CSS selectors, I'd write:

```
doc.css("span[class='#{k}']").children
```