# How to exclude particular class name in CSS selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply background-color when a user mouse hover the  element whose class name is `"reMode_hover"`.

But I do not want to change color if the element **also** has `"reMode_selected"`

Note: I can only use CSS not javascript because I'm working within some sort of limited environment.

To clarify, my goal is to color the first  element on hover but not the second  element.

**HTML**

```
<a href="" title="Design" class="reMode_design  reMode_hover">
    <span>Design</span>
</a>

<a href="" title="Design" 
 class="reMode_design  reMode_hover reMode_selected">
    <span>Design</span>
</a>
```

I tried below hoping the first definition would work but it is not. What am I doing wrong?

**CSS**

```
/* do not apply background-color so leave this empty */
.reMode_selected .reMode_hover:hover 
{
}

.reMode_hover:hover 
{
   background-color: #f0ac00;
}
```

Answer (score 291, accepted):

One way is to use the multiple class selector (no space as that is the descendant selector):

```css
.reMode_hover:not(.reMode_selected):hover 
{
   background-color: #f0ac00;
}
```

```html
<a href="" title="Design" class="reMode_design  reMode_hover">
    <span>Design</span>
</a>

<a href="" title="Design" 
 class="reMode_design  reMode_hover reMode_selected">
    <span>Design</span>
</a>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be: .reMode_hover:not('.reMode_selected'):hover 
In my experience those quotes are necessary.

Comment: @MakanTayebi You raise an excellent point regarding quotes around the selector. TL;DR: It is indeed best to use them. Thorough explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578880/1772379 .

Comment: Is that still the case? Haven't tried this in other browsers, but in the latest version of Firefox that I'm working in, the `:not` selector only worked when I _removed_ the quotes.

Answer (score 34):

In modern browsers you can do:

```
.reMode_hover:not(.reMode_selected):hover{}
```

Consult http://caniuse.com/css-sel3 for compatibility information.

Answer (score 13):

## Method 1

The problem with your code is that you are selecting the `.remode_hover` that is a **descendant** of `.remode_selected`. So the first part of getting your code to work correctly is by removing that space

```
.reMode_selected.reMode_hover:hover
```

Then, in order to get the style to not work, you have to override the style set by the `:hover`. In other words, you need to counter the `background-color` property. So the final code will be

```
.reMode_selected.reMode_hover:hover {
  background-color:inherit;
}
.reMode_hover:hover {
  background-color: #f0ac00;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgaG8/)

## Method 2

An alternative method would be to use `:not()`, as stated by others. This will return any element that doesn't have the class or property stated inside the parenthesis. In this case, you would put `.remode_selected` in there. This will target all elements that don't have a class of `.remode_selected`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgaG8/1/)

However, I would not recommend this method, because of the fact that it was introduced in CSS3, so browser support is not ideal.

## Method 3

A third method would be to use jQuery. You can target the `.not()` selector, which would be similar to using `:not()` in CSS, but with much better browser support

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgaG8/3/)

Comment: You should remove your "Method 3" that mentions jQuery since the OP specifically said "not javascript" for a solution.