# JTextPane, text/html content: nested HTML element do not inherit font size?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I have this code to display `HTML` formatted string:

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
        pane.setContentType("text/html");
        pane.setEditable(false);
        pane.setText(
            "<html>" +
                "<body style='font-size:18px'>" +
                    "<h1>Error:</h1>" +
                    "<p>" +
                        "Could not read the file <code>none.txt</code>. " +
                        "Perhaps it does not exist in the specified location, " +
                        "or possibly there is no access to it" +
                    "</p>" +
                "</body>" +
            "</html>");
        add(pane);
```

But this is the output:

[image]

You can see that the `none.txt` string doesn't inherit the font size of its enclosing paragraph, although this is what's supposed to happen in HTML ([see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3jvz69k4/)).

How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps end the body tag before the <code> tags, then restate the body tag afterwards? Example:  "Could not read the file </body><code> none.txt</code><body>

Comment: @joey942, I don't see the sense in it. Why excluding `<code>none.txt</code>` from `<body>` should work, and how can we have more than one `<body>`? anyway, tried that, it completely ignores the whole content of `<p>`, and all I see is the "Error:" text.

Comment: Then perhaps do this:           <div id="notbody"><code>none.txt</code></div>        Then in CSS, #notbody{ // set font size to what you want it to be}              These are just suggestions, I have not tried them out myself.

Comment: I may have found something for you, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201948/how-to-exclude-particular-class-name-in-css-selector        It has information on the not selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely a bug.  You can work around it by adding explicit inheritance in the CSS, with a `<style>` element:

```
pane.setText(
    "<html>" +
        "<style>\ncode { font-size: inherit; }\n</style>" +
        "<body style='font-size:18px'>" +
            "<h1>Error:</h1>" +
            "<p>" +
                "Could not read the file <code>none.txt</code>. " +
                "Perhaps it does not exist in the specified location, " +
                "or possibly there is no access to it" +
            "</p>" +
        "</body>" +
    "</html>");
```

Comment: That's annoying. Now I have to add `inherit` for every kind of block I may ever use? `bold`, `code`, etc... ?

Comment: I don’t think `<b>` needs it.  Probably just the ones which change the font family.  `<code>`, `<pre>`, `<samp>`, and possibly `<kbd>`.