# How to use a CSS Rule except on Homepage

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using this code

```
#main-header::after {
content: "";
background-image: url('xxxx');
background-size:cover;
opacity: 1.0;
top: -45%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
```

And I want it work in all pages except in the homepage because I have a fullwidth slider, how can I do it? I'm using this custom CSS on Wordpress. Thanks!!

Comment: In the home page create the custom style to override this. home page:  `#main-header::after { /*custom overriding styles */}`

Comment: home page body must have some unique class. Target this using .home #main-header::after{ override the styles here or display:none} where .home is the class on body tag for home page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use class exclude selector using the body class like [How to exclude particular class name in CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201948/how-to-exclude-particular-class-name-in-css-selector)

so your code will become:

```
body:not(.home) #main-header::after {
content: "";
background-image: url('xxxx');
background-size:cover;
opacity: 1.0;
top: -45%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php if(!is_home()){ ?>
<style type="text/css">
#main-header::after {
content: "";
background-image: url('xxxx');
background-size:cover;
opacity: 1.0;
top: -45%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
</style>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Answers are always welcome, but including a brief explanation of *how* the above solves the problem would make it more useful to others.