# How to place a logo in RMarkdowns' ioslides except on the title slide?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am looking for a way to create a custom css file, which allows me put a logo on each slide except on the title slide. So far, I was able to embed it to each slide using:

```
 body {
   background-image: url("log.png");
   background-size: 20%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 3% 96%;
 }
```

In addition, I don't want to set the logo in YAML but rather directly in the css file and it is not supposed to be part of the footer. I'm stuck and any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The title slide has class `title-slide`.  This question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16201948/2554330 gives ways to exclude a particular class.  You'll probably need to set your logo on the `slide` element, rather than on the `body` element, for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `style.css`:

```
 slides > slide:not(.title-slide) {
   background-image: url("log.png");
   background-size: 20%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 3% 96%;
 }
```

and then include the style using YAML

```
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: style.css
```

Comment: Is it possible to have two logos one at the bottom and one on top?

Comment: @user1700890:  I don't know.  You should post this as a new question, and maybe someone who does know will answer.