# Apply "padding: env()" to the whole body except a special class

Tags: html, css, iphone

I would like to optimize my website for the iPhone X (and above). By default, there is a safearea that I want to change.

Everything on my website should have this safearea, so I gave the whole body

```
padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
```

But I got some fullscreen background images I don't want this padding to apply to.
`padding: 0;` doesn't work.

How do I "negate" this padding for my background images?
I also tried it with

```
body:not (.background) { padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);}
```

but it also didn't work.

I attach a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4fko5tju/) so you can see what the structure of my code is.
Only problem is: you will only see this on an iPhone X or above, not in the devtools.

Thank you very much.
If you need further information, please let me know.

Comment: Check out this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201948/how-to-exclude-particular-class-name-in-css-selector or this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/geatR/1/ Let me know if those work

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for me. As soon as I apply "padding: env();" to the body I can't "revert" it for my class inside the body. That's why I'am looking for something to override this padding.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what your asking, if so, this should fix your issue.

Put a `div` inside the HTML of your document that sits directly inside the `body` tag:

```
<body>
   <div id="body-content">
      <!-- The content of your page will all go here -->
   </div>
</body>
```

And then for you padding, just apply it to your content `div`:

```
#body-content {
   padding: env(safe-area-inset-top)
      env(safe-area-inset-right)
      env(safe-area-inset-bottom)
      env(safe-area-inset-left);
}
```

This should allow the background of your body to reach the edges of the screen while your content is still optimized for mobile screens.

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is, that I want to do this in combination with wordpress and I can't (and don't want to) set up classes for every of my content elements, because it's dynamic. I thought it would be easier to exclude just some background image divs.