# How do I exclude specific classes when applying a style to my <body>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to reduce the brightness by everything on my page when I press a button, (filter: brightness(50%);) but I want 3 divs to remain the way they were.
(The divs are called something along the lines of "popup1", "popup2" and "popup3"

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
function showPopups()
document.getElementById("bodyID").classList.add("darken");

.darken {
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

I have experimented with the :not syntax but haven't found any good websites/other stackoverflow questions that explains it well enough.
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
My :not method is looking like this right now:

```
.darken:not(.avoid) {
filter: brightness(50%);
```

}

while my divs look like this:

```
<div id="popupID1" class="popup1 avoid">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201948/how-to-exclude-particular-class-name-in-css-selector

Comment: I tried some of them just now and it doesn't seem to work.
I added an extra class to my divs called "avoid" and wrote .darken:not(.avoid) { 
} 
but no success there either.

Comment: What you want is not possible, not this way. A filter applies to an a element and _all_ its content - this is practially the same issue, as already often discussed for `opacity`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/5770341/1427878 While opacity has no “counter-action”, here you could of course try and reverse the effect of your filter on those specific elements, by applying a brightness filter with a factor > 100%, but you’d have to see if that brings a desirable result.

Comment: That's a real shame. I have tried to add a brightness filter of over 100% to those divs but it becomes heavily saturated and ugly.