# Compare a full URI in a test in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am building a test using rspec. I have an image tag generated automatically, but I need to run the test by comparing if the URL generated by my helper is the one I need. it is an URL from googlemaps' API.

Here is my code:

```ruby
within ("data-hook.product_map") do
    should have_css('img src.http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=338x244&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=23.129,-82.38&center=23.129,-82.38&zoom=9')
end
```

The error I get when I run the test is:

```
Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '//' after ':'
```

Is there a way I can compare this string, or a way around this? Of course I need to run the tests anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`have_css` expects a valid css selector, according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp) the format is:

> Style `<a>` elements with a `target="_blank"`:
>
> ```
> a[target=_blank]
> { 
>   background-color:yellow;
> }
> ```

so try:

```
within ("data-hook.product_map") do
    should have_css('img[src=http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=338x244&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=23.129,-82.38,blue&center=23.129,-82.38&zoom=9]')
end
```

**Edit**

According to [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none) you should put quotes around the value:

```
within ("data-hook.product_map") do
    should have_css('img[src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=338x244&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=23.129,-82.38,blue&center=23.129,-82.38&zoom=9"]')
end
```

Comment: It throws another error now the equal in the hash doesn't belongs there **Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected ':' after '[:equal, "http"]'** is the error now

Comment: Now we are talking, worked like a charm, thank you for your time