# Why do I need quotes around an attribute value with a @ in a CSS selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using the following to access specific **DOM elements with the placeholder** `"Serial"`

```
$('input[placeholder=Serial]')
```

And it's **working fine**. I have some **other DOM elements** having placeholder of `"@SAL"`, when I try to access them using:

```
$('input[placeholder=@SAL]')
```

It **throws this error**

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[placeholder=@SAL]

But when I try to **access the same using double quotes** `"` around `@SAL` it's working **fine**.

Now **the question** is, why does `$('input[name=Serial]')` work fine i.e. without the double quotes around the placeholder value but `$('input[placeholder=@SAL]')` throw the above said error?

***P.S*** I know it's a bad idea to access DOM elements based upon their placeholders (as they may change), but I was just curious that why is it not working in this specific case...

Comment: @ Kamran: I expect it's probably lack of research effort. This information is *very* easy to find -- it's in the jQuery docs, the CSS selectors docs, on MDN...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's right there in the docs -

> Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Note that Unicode is code-by-code equivalent to ISO 10646 (see [UNICODE] and [ISO10646]).

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

A selector that begins with the '@' is not a valid selector but can be remedied by using quotes or by escaping the characters in question.

Answer (score 1):

Because `@` is a special character and this either needs to be escaped like this:

```
$('input[placeholder=\\@SAL]')
```

*(The actual selector has one backslash, but because this is a JavaScript string literal, we have to use `\\` to get a single backslash into the selector.)*

or select it with string value with quotes like this:

```
$('input[placeholder="@SAL"]') // this does not need to escaped.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between your two situations is the @ symbol, therefore you should either escape it or I would quote it to make it a string. It should most definitely work that way.

Comment: @RakeshShetty Poster is just trying to help, no need to be so rude

Comment: Just helping the OP out obviously he didn't come to that conclusion lol

Comment: @A.Wolff I know but this is not an answer or he can post this as comment

Comment: @RakeshShetty He cannot post comment (rep<50) but you are right that's not an answer. But wait, poster seems new here on SO ;) EDIT: `member for 1 year` well, i'd say quite 'new' then

Comment: @user2313721: The question is **"why"**, not "what's different".

Comment: It says I have to be of a certain reputation to post a comment on a question, so I answered. And my answer was a real answer lol