# Select element by value

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

The website I am trying to automate has some radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="outputFormat" value="quicken" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="outputFormat" value="xls">
<input type="radio" name="outputFormat" value="csv" checked="on">
<input type="radio" name="outputFormat" value="quickbooks">
```

I am trying to select the 'CSV' option by CSS selector as that appears to be the only way to get it.  This is what im trying:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("value=\"csv\"")).click();
```

However, this is giving me an invalid selector error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix your CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=csv]")).click();
```

Note that, the main problem with your selector is missing `[` and `]` for the attribute check. There is also no need to [put `csv` into quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none) in this case. `[value=csv]` would also work, but it's better to be explicit about the element your are locating.