# AngularJS Protractor: select div with ng-show directive

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I need to access to a div with a *ng-show* directive WITHOUT using xpath

```
<div ng-show="my_error && dirty_field">
  Custom error message.
</div>
```

I tried these but it doesn't work properly

```
element(by.css('[ng-show=my_error && dirty_field]'));
```

and

```
element(by.model('my_error && dirty_field'));
```

How can I do?

Comment: Try the below code.    element(by.css("[ng-show='my_error && dirty_field']"));

You missed to add "'"  quotes for ng-show value

Comment: I tried also with quotes (it doesn't work anyway) but somewhere somebody has written that quotes should not be used..

Comment: Can you please post the error message  that you are getting

Comment: It simple throws *Expected true to be falsy* in any case...

`var el =  element(by.css("[ng-show='my_error && dirty_field']"));

expect(el.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
expect(el.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();`

but with xpath it works correctly..

Comment: I was using wrong Element Finder comparison... I must use isDisplayed instead of isPresent..

Answer (score 1):

Just to add few points here.

First of all, you definitely need the quotes around the `ng-show` value in this case:

```
element(by.css('[ng-show="my_error && dirty_field"]'));
```

This is because the value contains non-alphanumeric characters. See this related thread:

- [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)

Also, I don't think you should use the `dirty_field` part in your locator. This sounds like a more technical variable used in the form validation logic. I'd use the "contains" check instead to check the `my_error` part only (note how I've removed the quotes in this case - the value is *alphanumeric*):

```
element(by.css('[ng-show*=my_error]'));
```

Also note that you can use the `$` shortcut instead of `element(by.css())`:

```
$('[ng-show*=my_error]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cab deal with the properties this way in doing protractor testing.

```
element.all(by.css('[ui-sref="about_us"]')).first();
element(by.css('[ng-click="clickme()"]')),
element(by.css('[ng-show*=show_me]'));
```