# selecting element in uib-dropdown menu

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ui-bootstrap, gulp-protractor

I Have a HTML code like this.

```
<div ng-if="!hide" class="dropdown pull-right" uib-dropdown>
    <a uib-dropdown-toggle href="" >
    <div class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-circle btn-xs pull-right comment-button"> 
        <span class="icon icon-chevron-down"></span>
    </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu " style="text-align: center;" role="menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
        <li role="divider" ng-if="showDelete"><a href="" ng-click="deleteItem($index)">delete </a></li>
        <li role="divider"><a href="" ng-click="Report()"> report</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When using in protractor facing an issue with uib-dropdown selection.
I written code like this:

```
var dropDown = element(by.css("div[uib-dropdown]"));
dropDown.element(by.css("a[uib-dropdown-toggle]"));
dropDown.element(by.css("a[ng-click=deleteItem($index)]")).click(); 
browser.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: what is the error thrown

Comment: Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified.Thanks @Danny.this error getting in second line i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.selectMenuOption = function (option) {  //menu item to click
    var dropdown = element(by.className('dropdown pull-right'));        
    dropdown.click();
    dropdown.element(by.tagName('ul')).all(by.tagName('li')).filter(function (elem) {
         return elem.getText().then(function (val) {
             return val.toUpperCase() === option.toUpperCase();
      })
   }).first().click();
}
```

Comment: throwing an error @Danny : Failed: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
  Stack:
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined

Comment: if it the correct response, can you mark it as the correct answer.So that others can get it easy

Answer (score 0):

The `a[ng-click=deleteItem($index)]` is actually an *invalid CSS selector*, you needed to [put the attribute value into quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5578845/771848):

```
dropDown.element(by.css('a[ng-click="deleteItem($index)"]')).click();
```

---

Though, I'd go for a partial match that appears to be more readable:

```
dropDown.element(by.css('a[ng-click*=deleteItem]')).click();
```

where `*=` means "contains".

---

Or, you can even go for a "link text" locator:

```
dropDown.element(by.linkText('delete')).click(); 
dropDown.element(by.partialLinkText('delete')).click();
```

Comment: tried above all the ways,still facing the same issue. @alecxe.please help me to solve

Comment: @Shiva okay. You should not be getting the same error though. What error(s) do you see? Thanks

Comment: still facing the same issue.the page contains two dropdown's it is unable to   locate the second element @alecxe