# Targeting element attributes in IE9+

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to target an h1 tag that has this attribute: `style=color:#230870` and apply a text-shadow. It works great, except in IE of course. Sample code I've found seem to work but my code is using the '#' and in IE it gets rendered as: `style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112);` in the H1.

[Here is my code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/jpfotoz/pen/XgXbaV)

```css
#mydiv h1[style*=red] {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #443E55;
}
#mydiv h2[style*=70] {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #ffcc00;
}
#mydiv h2[style*=rgb] {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
 <h1>THIS IS A REGULAR H1 TAG</h1>
 <h1 style="color:red">THIS IS H1 WITH "red" AS IT'S ATTRIBUTE VALUE AND A DROP SHADOW</h1>
 <h1 style="color:#230870">THIS H1 WITH BLUE #230870 CSS ATTRIBUE VALUE WITH A DROP SHADOW</h1>
  <h1 style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112);">THIS H1 WITH BLUE #230870 BUT IE RENDERS THE ATTRIBUTE as: 'style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112)'</h1>
  
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why target an h1 tag with a style attribute and not some unique id identifier?

Comment: Those are targeting examples. (Obviously only one H1 per page) -- I need to actually target any value in the rgb/rgva value - pending on is generated in my CMS.

For example: 
<h1 style="color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
<h1 style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);">

The CSS would target each one, with different color shadow, pending on what is selected in the CMS.  I can't target just the 'rgb' in the code as the wrong shadow could be used.  Sorry if that wasn't clear in the beginning. (Newbie at writing questions)

Comment: @VivekN -- I can't add id's or classes -- it's set in the CMS which I don't have control over. That is a future possibility - but for now I need a css solution.

Comment: I assume the use of `h2` in the CSS is a typo, and here is a possible duplicate, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none), which clarifies how to use attribute selector properly

Comment: Also, IE doesn't render `rgb(35, 8, 112)`, but it will return a hex color value, like `#230870` as `rgb()` when you query which color is set, which mean, you can still use `h2[style*='70']` in the CSS to target it. Here you can read more about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/how-to-get-hex-color-value-rather-than-rgb-value

Comment: What are you doing wrong? Let's start with multiple `<h1>` elements. You should have only 1 per page. Even if you can't edit the h1 element itself (which I'm certain you can) you can still target the h1 with the other element identifiers; `#mydiv h1` but really why not just `h1 { my styles...}`?

Comment: @SethWarburton - yes of course -- I'm just trying to find the right combonation.  OVBIOUSLY only one H1 per page.

Comment: Then simply use a class to scope that page and target the h1 directly; `.my-page h1 { my styles }`. I can't see how you would need anything more than that.

Comment: @SethWarburton -  Here's the tag and css. What's wrong?  It doesn't render at all. 

<style> 
h1[style*=35] {border:1px solid red; text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(135, 206, 235, 1);}
</style>
<h1 style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112);">THIS H2 HAS style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112)</h1>

Comment: Ugh.. I missed the tick marks.  This works. Thanks @SethWarburton!!
        h1[style*='35'] {text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(135, 206, 235, 1);}

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't render @photoman? And, why not just use `h1 {border:1px solid red; text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(135, 206, 235, 1);}`?

Comment: @photoman does my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML are all `h1`, but your CSS target `h2` (2nd and 3rd)

Also use `h1[style*="70"]` to target the 2nd one

```css
h1[style*=red] {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #443E55;
}
h1[style*="70"] {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #ffcc00;
}
h1[style*=rgb] {
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #ffcc00;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
 <h1>THIS IS A REGULAR H1 TAG</h1>
 <h1 style="color:red">THIS IS H1 WITH "red" AS IT'S ATTRIBUTE VALUE AND A DROP SHADOW</h1>
 <h1 style="color:#230870">THIS H1 WITH BLUE #230870 CSS ATTRIBUE VALUE WITH A DROP SHADOW</h1>
  <h1 style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112);">THIS H1 WITH BLUE #230870 BUT IE RENDERS THE ATTRIBUTE as: 'style="color: rgb(35, 8, 112)'</h1>
  
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need to prefix your selectors with `#mydiv`. That's just redundant code, overspecifying your selectors.

Comment: @SethWarburton yes, thanks, you are right, the less rule defined, the faster the selector =D I updated my code

Answer (score 0):

As there's only one h1 per page you can use a much simpler selector, there's no need to overspecify it. This should do what you need:

```
h1 {
   border:1px solid red; 
   text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(135, 206, 235, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. This was the solution, not sure who commented first. I was missing the tic marks in the search.

```
    h1[style*='35'] {text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(135, 206, 235, 1);}
```