# JavaScript - add eventListener to all input with type range

Tags: javascript, input, range, addeventlistener

I try to achieve a functionality, that input-Elements with the type `range` allways parse their value to a span element which is located after the range.

Console does not output any issues, is it possible, that i can't define the type of the input in the

**HTML**

```html
<div class="rowitem rowinput w100">
    <label for="person">Units</label>
    <input type="range" id="units" name="units" min="1" max="30" value="1" step="1" />
    <div class="range_sel_cont">
        <span class="range_sel">1</span>
         Units
    <div>
</div>
```

**JS (Vanilla)**

```js
    let ranges = document.getElementsByTagName('input[type=range]');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < ranges.length; i++) {
       ranges.addEventListener ("change", function () {
           let show = this.closest('.range_sel');
           show.innerHTML = this.value;
        });
    };
```

Comment: You did not double check to make sure that [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) actually does what you think it does.

Comment: Right...closest only looks **up** the ancestor tree

Comment: you're missing quotation marks around `range`, remember how we select it in CSS? `input[type="range"]`. IMP: you **CANNOT** use the same type of quotation marks, like in the above quote you're using single quotation marks (**'** , **'**)in `getElementsByTagName`, so while specifying `range` you will **have** to use double quotation marks (**"** , **"**)

Comment: @AdarshDubey The quotations are not required. See: [CSS attribute selectors: The rules on quotes (", ' or none?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578845/css-attribute-selectors-the-rules-on-quotes-or-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things:

- You should be adding the event listener to the item in `ranges` at index `i`, not `ranges` itself (which is an HTMLCollection)
- [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) gets the closest parent element that matches the selector. The element you are trying to select inside the event listener is the child of a sibling. You can select it by getting the input's [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling).
- There is no element with the tag `input[type=range]`. If you want to get all elements that match that selector, use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
let ranges = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=range]');
for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
  ranges[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    let show = this.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.range_sel');
    show.innerHTML = this.value;
  });
};
```

```html
<div class="rowitem rowinput w100">
  <label for="person">Units</label>
  <input type="range" id="units" name="units" min="1" max="30" value="1" step="1" />
  <div class="range_sel_cont">
    <span class="range_sel">1</span> Units
    <div>
    </div>
```